# would this procedure calculate the no of rows ? how do i call this procedure from php?

Tags: php, mysql

test1 is procedure which counts rows of table which is being created after passing two variables v_col1 and v_col2. when I run this on MySQL, it shows

"MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0020 sec)"

however I am not able to call this from php.

```
 Delimiter $$
create procedure test1()
BEGIN
BLOCK1: begin
declare v_col1 int(10);                     
declare no_more_rows1 boolean default FALSE;  
declare cursor1 cursor for              
select content_id
from   topic_list where topic_id=1;
declare continue handler for not found  
set no_more_rows1 = TRUE;           
open cursor1;
LOOP1: loop
fetch cursor1
into  v_col1;
if no_more_rows1 then
close cursor1;
leave LOOP1;
end if;
BLOCK2: begin
  declare v_col2 int(10);
  declare no_more_rows2 boolean default FALSE;
  declare cursor2 cursor for
    select content_id
    from   content_upvotes
    where  u_id_upvoter = 1;
  declare continue handler for not found
   set no_more_rows2 = TRUE;
  open cursor2;
  LOOP2: loop
    fetch cursor2
    into  v_col2;
    if no_more_rows2 then
        close cursor2;
        leave LOOP2;
    end if;
    select count(*) as mynum from (SELECT *from content_upvotes where content_id=v_col1) t1 join (select u_id_upvoter as user_id from content_upvotes where content_id= v_col2) t2 on t1.u_id_upvoter=t2.user_id ;
  end loop LOOP2;
  end BLOCK2;
  end loop LOOP1;
  end BLOCK1;
  end $$
  DELIMITER ;
```

please help me out here.

Comment: I downvoted you simply because you registered 2 account on SO, then duplicated the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808820/how-to-call-the-stored-procedure-from-php-and-get-results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, an observation (which is not an answer to the question you asked)...

This procedure seems *overly* complicated for whatever it is that it's supposed to be accomplishing.

---

**Q: Will this procedure calculate the no of rows?**

**A:** If you are asking if this procedure will return a "count of rows"...

It will conditionally, on the condition that `cursor1` returns at least one row, and that `cursor2` returns at least one row at some point during the execution of the procedure. To answer your first question...

**Yes,** it's possible that `mynum` (the output argument of the procedure) will be populated with a "count of rows".

The "count" returned will be from the *very last* execution of the `select count(*)` query (at the bottom of loop2). The results from any previous executions of the `select count(*)` query will be discarded.

If `cursor1` does not return a row, then the answer is **No**, the procedure won't return any "count of rows". Also, if a row is never returned from `cursor2` then the answer is also **No**.

---

**Q: How do I call this procedure from PHP?**

**A:** Assuming that you are using PDO, you can use a pattern like this:

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("CALL test1(?)");
$sth->bindParam(1, $return_val, PDO::PARAM_INT, 20);
$sth->execute();

print "call to msyql stored procedure test1 returned $return_val\n";
?>
```

---

And to follow up on my initial observation... I'm baffled as to any good reason why this procedure exists.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

The code example above addresses the original procedure definition which had an `OUT` parameter.  The procedure definition in the question has been changed to remove the `OUT` parameter, and the `SELECT ... INTO var` SQL statement has been changed to remove the `INTO var`. The modified procedure has the potential to return zero, one or more resultsets.

To execute the procedure (with no parameters) and retrieve all of the resultsets from the procedure, you could use a pattern something like this:

```
 <?php
 $sth = $dbh->prepare("CALL test1()");
 $sth->execute();

 $results = array();
 do {
    $rowset = $sth->fetchAll();
    if($rowset) {
       $results [] = $rowset;
    }
 } while ($sth->nextRowset());

 ?>
```

Comment: sorry. I shouldn't have put mynum as out variable. would this return resultsets( i.e rows) ? is so , how do I call it?

Comment: sorry. I shouldn't have put mynum as out variable. I have edited the question procedure bit. would this return resultsets( i.e rows) ? if so , how do I call it?